# Rails query speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Just discovered strange behavior:

```
Model.includes(:another).all
Model.includes(:another)
```

The first one is 5 times faster than the second, could you explain it?
How to achieve first method's speed but returning `Relation` instance for use with Kaminari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably only virtual difference, just on logs. When checked it in Firebug, loading speed was identical.